# Why ternary diagrams work

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to understand why [ternary diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot) work. In order that the [altitude criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot#Reading_values_on_the_ternary_plot) be valid, if I correctly understand, given equilateral triangle $ABC$, whose vertices I name as the three phases $A,B,C$, the sum $XL'+XM'+XN'$ (see figure on the left; I use the same notation for sides and their length) of the distances of point $X$, contained inside the triangle, from the sides must equate the height of $ABC$. Why does that holds?

[image]

Moreover, in order that the [intersection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot#Reading_values_on_the_ternary_plot) hold and the ratios between the three phases be respected, I would say that, if we respectively call $L,M$ and $N$ the intersection point between straight line $\overline{CX}$ and $AB$, between straight line $\overline{AX}$ and side $BC$ and between straight line $\overline{BX}$ and side $AC$, I would say that the following equality should hold:$$\frac{AN}{CN}=\frac{AL}{BL}\frac{BM}{CM}$$because, if $a,b$ and $c$ respectively are the quantities of phases $A,B$ and $C$, I would say that the equality is equivalent to $\frac{c}{a}=\frac{b}{a}\frac{c}{b}$ (where the factors correspond to each other: $\frac{c}{a}=\frac{AN}{CN}$ etc.). How can it be proved?

While ternary diagrams are ubiquitous in several sciences, like geology, I can find nothing explaining the mathematical foundations of such diagrams, why they work.
I suspect that what I have said can be proved by using elementary or analytic geometry, but I must admit that I can find no way to prove them to myself (there is possibly some rust on my knowledge of elementary geometry). I thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: The altitude criterion comes from [Vivani's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem). Are you also asking how to show that the "intersection method" works?

Comment: @user86418 Thnak you very much! Viviani's theorem is easy, but very nice! Yes, I'm asking why the "intersection method" works, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram below uses a slightly different labeling ($A$, $B$, and $C$ are opposite $L$, $M$, and $N$ respectively). Here's a computational justification of the intersection method. (It's possible there are simpler arguments.)

Let $(x, y, z)$ denote spatial Cartesian coordinates. Without loss of generality, the triangle lies in the plane with equation $x + y + z = 1$. If $X = (a, b, c)$, then the labeled points have Cartesian coordinates
\begin{align*}
A &= (1, 0, 0), & B &= (0, 1, 0), & C &= (0, 0, 1), \\
L &= \frac{1}{b + c}(0, b, c),&
M &= \frac{1}{a + c}(a, 0, c),&
N &= \frac{1}{a + b}(a, b, 0).
\end{align*}
By the Cartesian distance formula,
$$
XA^{2} = (1 - a)^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}
   = (b + c)^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}
   = 2(b^{2} + bc + c^{2})
$$
and
$$
LA^{2} = 1 + \frac{b^{2} + c^{2}}{(b + c)^{2}}
  = 2\frac{b^{2} + bc + c^{2}}{(b + c)^{2}}.
$$
Thus $\dfrac{XA}{LA} = b + c = 1 - a$. By similar calculations (or symmetry of the labels!), $\dfrac{XB}{MB} = a + c = 1 - b$ and $\dfrac{XC}{NC} = a + b = 1 - c$.

It follows that
$$
\frac{LX}{LA} = 1 - \frac{XA}{LA} = a,\quad
\frac{MX}{MB} = b,\quad
\frac{NX}{NC} = c,
$$
so that $\dfrac{LX}{LA} + \dfrac{MX}{MB} + \dfrac{NX}{NC} = a + b + c = 1$, as claimed.

[image: Coordinates in a ternary diagram]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and very clear answer! There is one thing that I cannot infer: I think that $\frac{AM}{CM}=\frac{AN}{BN}\frac{BL}{CL}$ must hold, but I don't see a way to deduce it... $\infty$ thanks again!

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide: You're welcome! And your suspicions are correct, as can be checked with the distance formula:$$MA=\frac{c\sqrt{2}}{a + c},\quad MC=\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{a + c}, \qquad\therefore \frac{MA}{MC} = \frac{c}{a}.$$The other ratios are similar.

Comment: I see: $\frac{AN}{BN}=\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{BL}{CL}=\frac{c}{b}$. I heartily thank you! Moreover, it can be esaily checked by means of similarity of triangles that $\frac{LX}{LA}=\frac{d(X,BC)}{h}$ (where $h$ is the height of $ABC$), which proves that the "altitude method" and the "intersection method" are equivalent.

Comment: ...one interesting thing more: your calculation for the ratios shows that $\frac{BN}{AN}=\frac{LX/LA}{MX/MB}=\frac{\text{quantity of phase }A}{\text{quantity of phase }B}$, which shows that we can calculate the ratios between the phases on the sides of the triangle.